# Unsafe Image manipulation causing program exit

Tags: c#, unsafe

I am experimenting with some basic image manipulation using `unsafe` code. I am then accessing a pixel with `bmp.GetPixel` and this is causing the program to "stop working". I have no idea how to debug this.

Am I not doing something in the Treshold method that I should be doing?

```
var imageFilename = @"foo.jpg";
var im = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageFilename);

Threshold(im, 2);

// this line causes it to stop working without an exception
im.GetPixel(0,0);



static void Threshold(Bitmap bmp, int thresh)
{
    BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    unsafe
    {
    byte* p = (byte*)(void*)bmData.Scan0.ToPointer();
    int h = bmp.Height;
    int w = bmp.Width;
    int ws = bmData.Stride;

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        byte* row = &p[i * ws];
        for (int j = 0; j < w * 3; j += 3)
        {
        row[j] = (byte)((row[j] > (byte)thresh) ? 255 : 0);
        row[j + 1] = (byte)((row[j + 1] > (byte)thresh) ? 255 : 0);
        row[j + 2] = (byte)((row[j + 2] > (byte)thresh) ? 255 : 0);
        }
    }
    }

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
}
```

**Update**: For some reason, I discovered that using a different pixel format `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` solved the problem. Why? The input image is greyscale.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" ... I can't replicate your problem - code works as-is, and I can save the resulting image after the call to `GetPixel`... I tried a few images I have, could be image related, could be something specific to your setup. I am using VS2015 Community Edition. Either way, it's not your code.

Comment: Strange, is that with using `bmp.PixelFormat` in the lockbits? I have a sneaky feeling it may be something to do with VS 2017 RC.

Comment: Yes, your code, as-is. The issue is grayscale - it's a 16 bits-per-pixel image, not 24 - you're reading past the image in unsafe code.

Comment: if it's a greyscale image, you only have one or two bytes per pixel. And actually you are reading 3 bytes per pixel :)

Comment: @user3791372 - Revenge downvoting isn't nice. I'm not the one that downvoted your question, BTW. In fact, i'll upvote now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is specifically image format. Grayscale images are 8 or 16 bits per pixel (depending on the image), not 24 bits per pixel; you're reading from (and more detrimentally, writing to) memory locations past the image - unsafe code does not check array bounds, so no exception is thrown.

For example, for 16-bit grayscale, re-write the inner loop:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < w * 2; j += 2)
    {
       row[j] = (byte)((row[j] > (byte)thresh) ? 255 : 0);
       row[j + 1] = (byte)((row[j + 1] > (byte)thresh) ? 255 : 0);
    }
```

The program "stops working" as you attempt to work with the image after the unsafe code runs, due to corrupt memory - you wrote to memory not owned by the image.

You can also adjust your loop based on `bmp.PixelFormat`, and manipulate an appropriate amount of bits; this way your code will work for multiple image formats.

More info on [bits per pixel](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/concept_of_bits_per_pixel.htm)

Comment: how do you adjust for the different amount of bits per pixel format if you use `bmp.PixelFormat`?

Comment: @user3791372 it's an `enum`; you can build a `Dictionary<PixelFormat, int>` and store corresponding number of bits for each entry. Then, just look it up from that dictionary at run-time and use `if` statements in your loop to access corresponding number of bits.

Comment: or I could use `Image.GetPixelFormat(bmp.PixelFormat)` ;)

Comment: @user3791372 Cool, I didn't know this one, thanks! I think you mean `Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat)` - much better than my suggestion, Microsoft team thought of that! ;)